# How to execute a python script in bash in parallel

Tags: python, bash, parallel-processing

I am trying to run a bash script multiple times on a cluster.  The issue however is I need to grab certain file names to fill the command which I only know how to do via python.

Note:I want to run the the last line (the line that calls the script) in parallel in groups of like two.  How can I do this?

I have thought of: outputting all commands to a .txt and catting that in parallel.  However, I feel that it is not the most efficient.

Thank you for any help

The script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys

cwd = os.getcwd()

for filename in os.listdir(cwd):
    if "_2_" in filename:
        continue
    elif "_1_" in filename:
        in1 = os.path.join(cwd, filename)
        secondread = filename.replace("_1.fastq_1_trimmed.fq","_1.fastq_2_trimmed.fq")
        in2 = os.path.join(cwd, secondread)
        outrename = filename.replace("_1.fastq_1_trimmed.fq",".bam")
        out = "/home/blmatsum/working/bamout/" + outrename
        cmd = "bbmap.sh ref=/home/blmatsum/working/datafiles/sequence.phages_clustered.fna in={} in2={} out={}".format(in1,in2,out)
        os.system(cmd)
```

an example of the command I want to run would be:

```
bbmap.sh ref=/home/working/datafiles/sequence.phages_clustered.fna in=/home/working/trimmed/SRR7077355_1.fastq_1_trimmed.fq in2=/home/working/trimmed/SRR7077355_1.fastq_2_trimmed.fq out=/home/working/bamout/SRR7077355.bam'
```

bbmap.sh ref=/home/working/datafiles/sequence.phages_clustered.fna in=/home/working/trimmed/SRR7077366_1.fastq_1_trimmed.fq in2=/home/working/trimmed/SRR7077366_1.fastq_2_trimmed.fq out=/home/working/bamout/SRR7077366.bam

Comment: Not sure Python is necessary or sensible here. I think many folks use **GNU Parallel** for fasta applications. Try clicking [edit] and adding 2-3 filenames and the corresponding commands you'd want to run. See also https://www.biostars.org/p/63816/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added a few example commands.  So doing bash is better?  Do you know how to do it via python, I was just curious for learning sake?  Also how would I go about doing it via bash?  I was having trouble going through the directory that contains all the names hence why I was using python to pull the command together.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Note that the way you're doing this is prone to serious security problems. Do not **ever** substitute variables into a shell command via simple string replacement without escaping.

Comment: Anyhow -- the only change you need to make to make things start in the background is to dump `os.system()` in favor of `subprocess.Popen()`. You should be using `subprocess` instead of `os.system` regardless; it's far more powerful (and often lets you avoid using a shell entirely, which `os.system` gives you no choice about).

Comment: Whoa I did not know that was a bad thing to do, thank you for that (super new to bash).  I am trying to use gnu parallel and have this: ```$  parallel --plus echo {%_1.fastq_1_trimmed.fq}  ::: *.trimmed.fq  | parallel 'bbmap.sh in1={}_1.fastq_1_trimmed.fq in2={}_2.fastq_1_trimmed.fq out={}.bam'``` my only confusion is how do i direct where my out goes (in terms of directory-want it to go /home/user/working/bamout/)  Thanks a lot